# Another Layer (1 Interface) vs. extending N Interfaces?

Tags: api, oop, interface, extend

I have an Data-Access Layer (SAP ABAP, but the language does not matter here) where I have 1 interface per entity/database-table, like

- IF_DATA_CONTRACT_POSITION->get_contract_positions( )
- IF_DATA_CONTRACT_HEAD->get_contract_header( )
- IF_DATA_OBJECT_CALC->get_object_calculations( )
- 40 more ...

These interfaces are implemented by the actual database-access class-impls and a generated caching-layer, which is pretty simple since the methods really do not have any parameters and just return "the relevant" data.

In certain consumers however, I require a filtered access to the returned data, specifically I need to get the data of all interfaces (~50) constrained by contract-position.

So, do you recommend to

- A) extend all interfaces by an optional parameter like IF_DATA_CONTRACT_POSITION->get_contract_positions([OPTIONAL-FILTER]) which means my impl and my caching-layer gets more complex
- B) should I create another interface IF_DATA_FILTER_CONTRACT_POSITION->set_contract_position_filter? for the sole purpose of explicitly filtering data-acesss

A) When extending every existing interface (the ~40-50 listed above) with the optional contract-position filter/constraint, the API is quite clean and would look like the following:

```
result = lo_data_object_calc->get_contract_positions( <FILTER> ).
```

As already mentioned, it would require me to extend every implementation, the data-access as well as the generated caching-layer.

B) With the explicit filter-interface IF_DATA_FILTER_CONTRACT_POSITION on the other hand, I would have yet another interface-layer around data-access and I could generate the uncoupled filtering impls. I would neither need to touch the actual data-access impl nor the generated cache-layer. However, the usage would be a little more clumsy, like

```
TRY.
     " down-cast from data-interface to filter-interface
     DATA lo_object_filter ?= lo_data_object_calc.
     lo_object_filter->set_contract_position_filter( <FILTER> ).
  CATCH could_not_cast. RAISE i-need-a-filter-impl!
ENDTRY.
result = lo_data_object_calc->get_object_calculations( ).
```

**Update 05.08.2014:** I decided to go with C) create a seperate filter-object which explicitly filters collections retrieved by e.g. get_contract_positions().

Answer (score 1):

I would go for solution A. 
1. If you later need to optimize your data retrieval you can do that in your db-access-class
2. You can use your filter in your where-clause and don't have to program by yourself
3. Someone else using your interfaces have to find, understand and use your filter interfaces/classes. I think it's easier if you have the filter as parameter inside your data access-methods

Comment: this is pro clean API, so you would bite the apple and overwork 50x data-access and cache-generation... thanks for this painful recommendation :)